# How to get process/PID responsible for creating outbound connection request (linux) (command line)

Tags: linux

I've got an alert from my firewall that a Debian virtual machine I have tried to download a miner virus.

tcpdump shows every minute it reaching out to:

```
07:55:01.379558 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49126: tcp 7300
07:55:01.379566 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:55:01.379576 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49126: tcp 2920
07:55:01.379584 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:55:01.379593 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49126: tcp 5840
07:55:01.379601 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:55:01.379609 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49126: tcp 8760
07:55:01.379617 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:55:01.379657 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49126: tcp 7300
07:55:01.379669 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:55:01.379680 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49126: tcp 4380
07:55:01.380974 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:55:01.381264 IP 192.168.1.205.49126 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.900223 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.900517 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 0
07:56:01.900553 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.900826 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 146
07:56:01.900967 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 0
07:56:01.901642 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 2920
07:56:01.901667 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901684 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 4380
07:56:01.901696 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901705 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 4380
07:56:01.901714 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901725 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 2920
07:56:01.901738 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901814 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 5840
07:56:01.901835 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901848 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 8760
07:56:01.901858 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901868 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 2920
07:56:01.901880 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901891 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 4380
07:56:01.901905 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901915 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 2920
07:56:01.901922 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901932 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 5840
07:56:01.901939 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.901949 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 2920
07:56:01.901955 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.902010 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.902039 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 4380
07:56:01.902065 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:56:01.902076 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49128: tcp 4380
07:56:01.902084 IP 192.168.1.205.49128 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.909829 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.910130 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49130: tcp 0
07:57:01.910157 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.910245 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 146
07:57:01.910375 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49130: tcp 0
07:57:01.911050 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49130: tcp 2920
07:57:01.911076 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.911096 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49130: tcp 4380
07:57:01.911108 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.911120 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49130: tcp 4380
07:57:01.911130 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.911141 IP 185.191.32.198.80 > 192.168.1.205.49130: tcp 2920
07:57:01.911414 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
07:57:01.911507 IP 192.168.1.205.49130 > 185.191.32.198.80: tcp 0
```

When I look at the firewall logs I can see it reaching out to: http://185.191.32.198/lr.sh

I can block it via the firewall, but what I'm interested in is understanding which PROCESS on my server is doing such queries, as these are outbound queries. So there is some kind of exploit or virus reaching out from the server to try and download this script.

I've tried various netstat and lsof commands I've found on here, but they don't catch the traffic when it's actually happening, they just dump out and so no active connections. Also, bear in mind, I have no local ports actively listening, these new outbound requests once a minute.

So how would one set something up to see which process / PID is making these outbound requests each minute?

Comment: Maybe using iptables with some logging options? Sorry I have no time for a deeper research.

Comment: Have you tried `netstat -anp` which shows PID for network connections ?

Comment: how would I think filter to know which one of these processes is responsible? From trying to figure it out previously, it also seems that when the process runs once every minute and the query finishes (within 1 second) it no longer shows under any netstat commands I run. Because it's not a listening port, just a single outbound http request that completes within a fraction of a second.

Comment: Maybe DROP SYN packets? Assuming that the process is using some reasonable connection timeout this should increase your chances to catch the traffic with lso/netstat.

Comment: You can have some info about this adresse on this [there](https://mxtoolbox.com/Problem/Blacklist/Spamhaus-ZEN/?page=prob_blacklist&ip=185.191.32.198&link=button&action=blacklist:185.191.32.198&showLogin=1&hidetoc=1&reason=127.0.0.10). The adresse seems to be in blacklist.

Comment: You might get more answers by posting your question on https://serverfault.com/ or https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using mbax's & Dude Boy input you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
  PID=$(netstat -nputw | grep 185.191.32.198)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      :
  else
      ps -ajxf
      echo "PID: ${PID}"
      exit
  fi
done
```

As a oneliner:

```
while true; do PID=$(netstat -nputw | grep 185.191.32.198); if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then :; else ps -ajxf; echo "PID: ${PID}"; break; fi; done
```

Edit: The original while timer 0.1 did not detect every attempt I tested, 0.01 did.
Edit 2: Using `true` uses up to 2% CPU, worth it when hunting ;)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Used your one liner: https://imgur.com/a/gu5Hova

Enough for me to continue my investigation, thanks so much. I'll try and split the points between you all, thanks all.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, which firewall are you using?

Comment: [Sophos XG home edition](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-xg-firewall-home-edition.aspx)

Comment: Why polling? This could miss some data if it happens quickly. Simply use the continuous mode of netstat.

Answer (score 3):

*netstat* can be used in continuous mode with the "-p" option to log the process initiating the connections, as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56453/how-can-i-monitor-all-outgoing-requests-connections-from-my-machine

Use the following command to log the connection attempts and pinpoint the initiating process:

```
sudo netstat -nputwc | grep 185.191.32.198 | tee /tmp/nstat.txt
```

Interrupt with *Ctrl-C* when you think the connection was logged.

```
less /tmp/nstat.txt
```

Then you can analyze the <PID> (replace with the pid of the process), its environment and threads with ps:

```
sudo ps -ef | grep <PID>
sudo ps eww <PID>
sudo ps -T <PID>
```

Comment: theory sounds great, but no getting any output: [what i see](https://imgur.com/a/HSZFqGu)

Comment: Not a good solution. The logger needs to the full PID information at runtime. Because at logs observation time the process may have exited.

Comment: Dave's Undies: You need to give some time for the pipe to buffer the lines (maybe 20-30 seconds). Or you could simply try without grep and tee:

    *sudo netstat -nputwc*

and then search in the output yourself. Something *should* show up, because we see in the tcpdump output that there *are* connections to that address. If not, just give it some time.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to research your problem using `nethogs` traffic monitoring tool. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linux-monitoring-network-traffic-with-nethogs/

It might take a while to catch the offending process .
And even if you catch it, it is possible the offending process is a transient vanishing script/program that is recreated with random names.

If your system is infected, then probably you will identify the infection is applied on a legitimated process or service.

Suggesting to scan your system with anti-virus as well.